# How to toggle button to change header to different color and back to original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the header to yellow to blue and then back to yellow on clicking button in jQuery

```js
$("#title2-button").click(function(){
  if ($("#title2").css("color", "yellow")) {
     $("#title2").removeClass("yellow");
     $("#title2").addClass("blue"); 
  } else {
    $("#title2").css("color", "yellow");
  }
});
```

```css
#title2{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id ="title2"> Weekends and Holidays Included</h2>
<button id="title2-button">Alter Second title</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) like below.

This code basically:

- When the button is clicked, it "toggles" the class `blue`. This means that if `#title2` has the class of blue, it removes it. If it doesn't have the class, it adds it. The `!important` is there to make sure that the class `blue` overrides the previous color of yellow.
- Since the default color  is yellow, if `toggleClass` removes the class, the color goes back to yellow. If it adds the class, then the color goes to blue (since `!important` is there, the color would be blue instead of yellow).

```js
$("#title2-button").click(function() {
  $("#title2").toggleClass("blue");
});
```

```css
#title2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
}
.blue {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id ="title2"> Weekends and Holidays Included</h2>
<button id="title2-button">Alter Second title</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggleClass` method to do that like this,

```
$("#title2-button").click(function(){
    $("title2").toggleClass("blue");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasClass` to check if class is present . Hope this is what you are looking for,thanks

```js
$("#title2-button").click(function(e){

if($('#title2').hasClass('yellow'))
{
$('#title2').removeClass('yellow').addClass('blue')
}
else
$('#title2').removeClass('blue').addClass('yellow')

})
```

```css
.yellow
{
color:yellow
}
.blue
{
color:blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yellow" id="title2">Some content</div>
<button id="title2-button">Alter Second title</button>
```